How do I import the cinemagoer module correctly? The example method doesn't work for me anymore
So I was using IMDBpy for a few years for a film database program I'm working on. But after its been changed to Cinemagoer, I haven't been able to get it working consistently.
import os
os.system('git+https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer')
os.system('pip install cinemagoer')
from imdb import Cinemagoer

# create an instance of the Cinemagoer class
ia = Cinemagoer()

# get a movie
movie = ia.get_movie('0133093')

It always produces the same "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imdb'" error.
Any help on this would be fantastic, I've love to get my program working again.

I think that the issue is that you're trying to run the install as part of the script. I was able to create a virtualenv, run the pip install, then use the example code to get the correct output.
Also, I noticed that in the code supplied you ran the input twice, once with github, once with PyPI. You only need one.

In the command prompt I've installed cinemagoer but it still doesn't recognise the imdb module... This used to work perfectly I can't see why it can't find the module anymore.

Are you running it in a virtual environment, or from your base env? If not, create a virtualenv to isolate any wacky dependency issues and rerun the install. If you're already working in a venv, then try this: run pip show cinemagoer. If you get an error, then run pip install cinemagoer then run the show command again. If that comes back with the version (et. al.) info, then open up the python command interpreter by running python3 then give it the command from imdb import Cinemagoer. It should return a new line in the interpreter.
